# Need optimization on multiple ng-repeat and ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, optimization

I've written a bit of Angular code but I'm not very proud of it.. Could anyone enlight me any possible optimization for the following :

** Context (not really needed I guess..) : **

I want to show the Average Length of different kind of trips grouping them by distinct companies.
In my Angular controller I'm initializing 4 Arrays of objects in my scope :

- tripDoneWithGuide --> List of trips that happened with a guide and are finished.
- tripOngoingWithGuide --> List of trips that happened with a guide and are not finished yet.
- tripDoneWithoutGuide --> List of trips that happened without a guide and are finished.
- tripOngoingWithoutGuide --> List of trips that happened with a guide and are not finished.

Each object in these list have 2 attributes :

- companyId --> The ID of the company wich realized the trip.
- avgLength --> The average length of a trip for this company.

Basically his is what any of them could look like :
   {
  "object": {
    "companyId": "1",
    "avgLength": "30"
  },
  "object2": {
    "companyId": "2",
    "avgLength": "60"
  }
}

So here's what I've done this far :

** Code part : **

```
<div ng-repeat="tDWG in tripDoneWithGuide">
<span> Average Length Trip for the Company : {{ tDWG.companyId }}</span>
<span> Avg Length Trip Done With Guide : {{ tDWG.avgLength }}</span>
<span ng-repeat="tDWOG in tripDoneWithoutGuide" ng-if="tDWG.companyId ==  tDWOG.companyId">
Avg Length Trip Done Without Guide : {{ tDWOG.avgLength }}
</span>
<span ng-repeat="tOWG in tripOngoinWithGuide" ng-if="tDWG.companyId ==  tOWG.companyId">
Avg Length Trip Ongoing With Guide : {{ tOWG.avgLength }}
</span>
<span ng-repeat="tOWOG in tripOngoinWithoutGuide" ng-if="tDWG.companyId ==  tOWOG.companyId">
Avg Length Trip Ongoing Without Guide : {{ tOWOG.avgLength }}
</span>
</div>
```

And it's kind of working.. I manage to get the result grouped by companies. 
But  1) I'm not really proud of this code, I feel like there's a lot of unnecessary looping...

2) When a company doesn't have a value of a kind of trip, there's nothing showing up, wich is looking weird.. I'd prefer use a default value like "0" showing up, like in a switch directive.

What kind of way of optimizing this would you advice me? I know this is not really advanced algorithmy but I'm still struggling...

And PS : Sorry for my english, and sorry if the post doesn't make sense, just tell me and I'll try to re-write it in another way.

Thanks to you all in advance

Comment: Hi ..if you need fix performance... try to don't use {{ myvar }} ..insted use ng-bind="myvar"

Comment: Do you intend to only include companies contained in tripDoneWithGuide?  That's how its working now since it is the top level loop.

Comment: @jbrown I didn't even notice and thought about that.. But no I wanna include all companies, so my code is totally wrong.. Thanks for noticing that

Comment: @lilli - I'd recommend that you handle collating your data either server-side or in your angular controller rather than trying to handle it in your html.

Comment: @jbrown Yeah, tomorrow morning I'll try doing some kind of Map to get all the infos by Company in my angular controller. Thanks a lot for the heads up !